# Why and how do the C++ implicit conversion rules distinguish templated conversion functions from non-templated?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to understand the implicit conversion rules in C++, and why the two implicit conversions in the following reduced case differ:

```cpp
// A templated struct.
template <typename T>
struct A {};

// A templated struct that can be constructed from anything that can be
// converted to A<T>. In reality the reason the constructor is templated
// (rather than just accepting A<T>) is because there are other constructors
// that should be preferred when both would be acceptable.
template <typename T>
struct B {
  template <typename U,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U, A<T>>>>
  B(U&& u);
};

// A struct that cna be implicitly converted to A<T> or B<T>.
struct C {
  template <typename T>
  operator A<T> ();

  template <typename T>
  operator B<T> ();
};

// Another struct that can be implicitly converted to A or B, but this time only
// a specific instantiation of those templates.
struct D {
  operator A<int> ();
  operator B<int> ();
};

// A function that attempts to implicitly convert from both C and D to B<int>.
void Foo() {
  B<int> b_from_c = C{};
  B<int> b_from_d = D{};
}
```

When I compile this with clang, it complains about the `b_from_c` initialization being ambiguous:

```
foo.cc:45:10: error: conversion from 'C' to 'B<int>' is ambiguous
  B<int> b_from_c = C{};
         ^          ~~~
foo.cc:24:3: note: candidate constructor [with U = C, $1 = void]
  B(U&& u);
  ^
foo.cc:33:3: note: candidate function [with T = int]
  operator B<T> ();
  ^
```

This totally makes sense to me: there are two paths to convert from `C` to `B<int>`.

But the part that puzzles me is why clang *doesn't* complain about the `b_from_d` initialization. The only difference between the two is that the problematic one uses a templated conversion function and the accepted one doesn't. I assume this has something to do with ranking in the implicit conversion rules or the overload selection rules, but I can't quite put it together and also if anything I would have expected `b_from_d` to be rejected and `b_from_c` to be accepted.

Can someone help me understand, ideally with citations of the standard, why one of these is ambiguous and the other isn't?

Comment: What clang version do you use? It doesn't compile to me: https://godbolt.org/z/757r8rzPW

Comment: The error there is the same as the one I got, right? If you delete the `b_from_c` line it's happy with the `b_from_d` line. That's the point.

Comment: Ah, sorry, got confused and thought you mean it doesn't compile on gcc, but does on clang. Probably too late for stackoverflow for me :) I guess it's the usual case of "templates are always the worst match" when selecting matching conversions, but let's wait for a language lawyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted text is from the C++20 standard, but links are to N4861.

[[dcl.init.general]/17.6.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#17.6.3) explains how such a copy-initialization is done:

> Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversions that can
> convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used) to a
> derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 12.4.2.5, and the best one is chosen through
> overload resolution (12.4). If the conversion cannot be done or is ambiguous, the initialization is
> ill-formed. The function selected is called with the initializer expression as its argument; if the
> function is a constructor, the call is a prvalue of the cv-unqualified version of the destination type
> whose result object is initialized by the constructor. The call is used to direct-initialize, according
> to the rules above, the object that is the destination of the copy-initialization.

According to 12.4.2.5 ([12.4.1.4 in N4861](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.copy))

> [...] Assuming that "*cv1* `T`" is the type of the object being initialized, with `T` a class type, the candidate functions
> are selected as follows:
>
> - The converting constructors (11.4.8.2) of `T` are candidate functions.
> - When the type of the initializer expression is a class type "*cv* `S`", the non-explicit conversion functions of `S` and its base classes are considered. [...] Those that are not hidden within `S` and yield a type whose cv-unqualified version is the same type as `T` or is a derived class thereof are candidate functions. A call to a conversion function returning "reference to `X`" is a glvalue of type X, and such a conversion function is therefore considered to yield `X` for this process of selecting candidate functions.
>
> In both cases, the argument list has one argument, which is the initializer expression.

The first bullet implies that the constructor `B::B<D>(D&&)` is a candidate function, which we'll call `F2`. The second bullet implies that `D::operator B<int>()` is a candidate function, which we'll call `F1`.

The first step to determine whether either `F1` or `F2` is better than the other is to determine the implicit conversion sequences involved ([[over.match.best.general]/2 ([over.match.best]/2 in N4861)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.best#2)). To call `F1`, the implicit conversion sequence is from `D{}` to the implicit object parameter of `D::operator B<int>` (which is of type `D&`). This is an identity conversion ([[over.ics.ref]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.best#2)). To call `F2`, the implicit conversion sequence is from `D{}` to the constructor's parameter type, `D&&`. This is also an identity conversion for the same reason.

Normally binding a `D` rvalue to an rvalue reference would be considered a better implicit conversion sequence than binding it to an lvalue reference; [[over.ics.rank]/3.2.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank#3.2.3). However, that rule is inapplicable in cases where either of the two bindings is to the implicit object parameter of a function that was declared without a ref-qualifier (as `D::operator B<int>()` was). The result is that neither of the two implicit conversion sequences is better than the other.

We then have to go through the tiebreaker rules in [[over.match.best.general]/2 ([over.match.best]/2 in N4861)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.best#2). We can see that bullet 2.2 does not apply to our case since our context is [over.match.copy], and not [over.match.conv] nor [over.match.ref]. Similarly bullet 2.3 does not apply. This means 2.4 controls: `F1` is not a function template specialization, and `F2` is. The overload resolution succeeds, selecting `F1`.

In the case of `b_from_c`, none of the tiebreaker rules apply, and the overload resolution is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I'd say it's point 4 from [Best viable function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function):

> F1 is determined to be a better function than F2 ... 
> ... 
> 4. or, if not that, F1 is a non-template function while F2 is a template specialization

In case of `C`, both the conversion function in `C` and the converting constructor `B` are template specializations and are equally viable.

In case of `D`, the conversion function in `D` is a non-template function and so is better than the converting constructor `B`.